# Zend Framework 2 - Automatically create Doctrine Entity Getters and Setters

Tags: model, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Is there a way to automatically create the getters and setters which [seems to be necessary](http://samminds.com/2012/07/a-blog-application-part-1-working-with-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/)?

Would save loads of time... couldn't find anything on the internet so far...

Thanks!

Comment: Some IDEs provide such a feature. [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/de/products/studio/) is one of them.

Comment: Agreeing with @DanielM Generating Setters and Getters is duty of an IDE, not anyones Framework.

Comment: This is sad. And - sorry to disagrere -I think its the duty of a framework to do the silly (and unnecessary) work for you. Ever tried `Django`? ;)

Comment: You can use php magic methods to get around having to write getters and setters, but it isn't really a good option. Just get an IDE to do the work for you. Along with the suggestions above, Netbeans will do it, and I think Eclipse will also.

Comment: Im currently testing PHPStorm, they say it can do this, too. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it out with `PHPStorm5` and you can do the following when editing an entity:

> Right-click > Generate > Getters and Setters > *select all variables* > Ok

You are done :)

Comment: Thank you, I never even thought about using that feature =)